# What happened to my reputation points?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, reputation

Yesterday I noticed that my reputation had decreased from 210 to 132. What could have caused this? I checked my activity and didn't see a decrease in any of the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rep was recalculated yesterday (27th). One of your answers was on a question that was deleted (question about slicing a pizza in to 6). Your answer was upvoted 7 times, so maybe it was a recalculation based on the now deleted answer.

I'm new to this though, so I'm kind of guessing. I do know that rep is recalculated based on changes in votes, changing acceptance, and answers or questions being deleted.

Comment: This is correct.  That answer had 8 upvotes and 1 downvote for a net of 7, and 78 reputation, which precisely makes up the difference.

Comment: Thanks for the help.